# service-worker no se carga en mi app PWA

Tags: javascript, html5, vue.js, pwa

Acabo de realizar una pequeña app `PWA` con `vue.js`, es una app simple mas que nada informativa. ahora que la puse en producción, no me carga el service-worker y por ende tampoco el manifest.js así que no es posible obtener la ventana que me permite  instalar mi app, cabe resaltar que tengo `https` instalado en mi dominio y las configuraciones de estos archivos las tengo de la siguiente manera:

```
importScripts("https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/4.3.1/workbox-sw.js");

importScripts(
  "/precache-manifest.dfde288e1e589cb2912c22a41a954486.js"
);

workbox.core.setCacheNameDetails({prefix: "my-app"});

self.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
  if (event.data && event.data.type === 'SKIP_WAITING') {
    self.skipWaiting();
  }
});

self.__precacheManifest = [].concat(self.__precacheManifest || []);
workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute(self.__precacheManifest, {});
```

y este es el `manifest.json`

```
{ 
   "name":"my-app",
   "short_name":"my-app",
   "theme_color":"#4DBA87",
   "icons":[ 
      { 
         "src":"./img/icons/android-chrome-192x192.png",
         "sizes":"192x192",
         "type":"image/png"
      },
      { 
         "src":"./img/icons/android-chrome-512x512.png",
         "sizes":"512x512",
         "type":"image/png"
      }
   ],
   "start_url":".",
   "display":"standalone",
   "background_color":"#000000"
}
```

y estos son los errores que me arrojan la consolo de chrome:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguna idea de cual es el problema aquí?

Comment: Tengo exactamente esos dos mismos errores. Ayuda pls.

Comment: ¿Podrías especificar los errores? Es decir, al parecer tus errores están en el SW y no los estás mostrando...